# How to install Mac OS X from Windows on MacBook Air?

Tags: windows, install

I have OS backup .dmg installation file. The problem is I have Windows 7 on my MacBook Air, and I do not have access to OS X to use Disk Utility to burn/restore the OS X image.

Is it possible to burn/restore .dmg file on usb stick from Windows?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need accessing it from windows.

Boot the computer holding the [option] key and choose the OSX recovery. Inside it there you'll have a very basic osx with its own Disk Utility to restore your DMG image to another USB.

Answer (score 1):

Several programs that support opening DMG files:

7-Zip will let you unzip the files.  You can rebuild and burn an ISO image from there.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/

A search around the web brought up TransMac as being able to directly burn a DMG to disk:
http://www.asy.com/sharetm.htm

Same goes for UltraISO:
http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/download.htm

... but I've not tried them.

Comment: But I do not want to burn on a disk. I would like to put it on my USB stick.

Comment: TransMac will allow you to create a bootable USB: USB Drive >> Format Disk >> Format with Disk Image, then select your DMG file.  You can do it with the 15-day trial.

Comment: It does found he drive when I restart my Mac, but it cannot load the installation. It says "Your computer needs to be restared.." What could be the issue?

Comment: Not sure.  Give Rostol's solution a shot, I forgot about that little trick and it is a better suggestion then mine.